I can't center the spherical gradient texture on the plane
I'm trying to follow this tutorial by BMBrice to create a rigged 2D eye texture. I've visited this tutorial a couple times in the past, but I get stuck at the first couple of steps. I can't center the spherical gradient texture on the plane. It's supposed to be centered and able to scale uniformly, I can't seem to fix it.
My setup

vs
His setup

And if I go the negative direction. It centers visually, but if I try to scale it, the center is off.


In the tutorial, he doesn't really touch the UV other than to make a butt joke. So, I'm not sure if I have to do something to the UV to get the texture centered.

Look at the signs of "Location"

I can't believe I missed that. It was just a matter of switching the type to texture on the mapping node.
